# Search bar: anchor tag enclosed in list item tags not selectable

Tags: javascript, html, django, search

I have a search bar in the style of like a google search bar where it gives suggestions based on the user input as you are typing in the text box. It filters through a bunch of items that are contained in an unordered list and runs myFunction() below to parse through the unordered list and display items. The only problem is that when you click the items that are displayed in the search bar, the link redirection doesn't work and I THINK it's because the onMouseButtonUp event doesn't register over the list item (because when I click down and hold the button down, it makes the item disappear if that makes sense)...thoughts?

```
<input style="border-radius: 7px 0px 0px 7px; border-right: 0px; resize: none" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" name="searchedItem" rows="1" class="form-control" form="searchForm" placeholder="What can we help you find?">
                  <ul id=myUL>
                    <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/{{ obj.productName }}">{{obj.productName}}</a></li>
                  </ul>



<script>
var UL = document.getElementById("myUL");
// hilde the list by default
UL.style.display = "none";

var searchBox = document.getElementById("myInput");

// show the list when the input receive focus
searchBox.addEventListener("focus",  function(){
    // UL.style.display = "block";
});

// hide the list when the input receive focus
searchBox.addEventListener("blur", function(){
    UL.style.display = "none";
});


function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    // if the input is empty hide the list
    if(filter.trim().length < 1) {
        ul.style.display = "none";
        return false;
    } else {
        ul.style.display = "block";
    }

    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

        // This is when you want to find words that contain the search string
     if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        li[i].style.display = "";
     } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    <!--// This is when you want to find words that start the search string
    /*if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().startsWith(filter)) {
        li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
    }*/-->
    }
}
</script>
```